# Django-Rest-Framework: Serializing Many to Many Model with a through in Post Request

Tags: django, post, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I am having really big trouble while trying to implement handling of POST request within DRF and Serializers. The error I have is following;

When I try to debug the issue, sporadically, request is handled successfully. I am really confused.

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for
> field `equipment_types` on serializer `FreightCreateSerializer`. The
> serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any
> attribute or key on the `Freight` instance. Original exception text
> was: 'Freight' object has no attribute 'FreightEquipmentType_set'.

My Models are;

```
    class EquipmentType(model.Model):  
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    
    class Freight(model.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        equipment_types = models.ManyToManyField(EquipmentType, through='FreightEquipmentType')    

    class FreightEquipmentType(model.Model):
    
        equipment_type = models.ForeignKey(
            EquipmentType,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
        freight = models.ForeignKey(
            Freight,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
        quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=2, default= 0)
```

My Serializers are,

```
class EquipmentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EquipmentType
        fields = "__all__"

class FreightEquipmentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = FreightEquipmentType
        fields = ('equipment_type', 'quantity', )

class FreightCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    equipment_types = FreightEquipmentTypeSerializer(many=True, source='FreightEquipmentType_set', read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Freight
        fields = "__all__"


    def create(self, validated_data):
        equipment_types_validated_data = validated_data.pop('FreightEquipmentType_set')
        freight = Freight.objects.create(**validated_data)
        equipment_type_serializer = self.fields['equipment_types']
        for each in equipment_types_validated_data:
            each['freight'] = freight
        equipment_types = equipment_type_serializer.create(equipment_types_validated_data)
        return freight
```

I would like to handle following post request.

```
{
  "name": "0",
  "equipment_types": [{
        "equipment_type": "8a9c1f57-c6c9-4bfa-84a8-2082d6c3d112",
        "quantity": 2
    }, {
        "equipment_type": "7242a8fb-3eba-4988-98fa-806c21562101",
        "quantity": 3
    }]
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research and try-outs. I finally found a blog post.

https://adnankayace.blogspot.com/2019/03/django-rest-framework-many-to-many_21.html

It solved my problem. Hope it helps others as well.